# Drawing N-width lines?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, drawing

Given a series of points, how could I calculate the vector for that line 5 pixels away? Ex:
Given:

```
   \
    \
     \
```

How could I find the vector for

```
   \  \
    \  \
     \  \
```

The ones on the right.

I'm trying to figure out how programs like Flash can make thick outlines.

Thanks

Comment: A vector is always, per definition, a nice straight line... It's even an infinitely long, nice, straight line. Also, five pixels in what direction? To the right? Along the normal to the first line?

Comment: Is this homework or personal project?

Comment: What would you want to happen if the original series of line segments was *not* simply a vertical line?

Comment: Personal project, I'm making a vector drawing application

Comment: Your example isn't a series of points, it starts with a line. Can you clarify?

Comment: Also, this is very different from the subject line of "n-width lines". Drawing several lines that are n pixels from each other doesn't help you draw a line of width n, as such. Two lines that are one pixel from each other don't necessarily have zero pixels between them at every step, depending on the line algorithm.

Comment: @calmh: What do you mean by the vector is infinite? The length of a vector represents the force. Do you you know something that can apply an infinite force on an object?

Comment: @Alerty I confused vector/ray. Never mind the infinite bit.

Comment: @user146780: What are you using to draw to the screen? Also, do you have some knowledge in trigonometry?

Comment: Well I was thinking of finding the normal of each vector and just going up...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A thick line is a polygon. (Let's forget about antialiasing for now)

[picture http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/863/linezi.png](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/863/linezi.png)

start = line start = vector(x1, y1)
end = line end = vector(x2, y2)
dir = line direction = end - start = vector(x2-x1, y2-y1)
ndir = normalized direction = dir*1.0/length(dir)
perp = perpendicular to direction = vector(dir.x, -dir.y)
nperp = normalized perpendicular = perp*1.0/length(perp)

perpoffset = nperp*w*0.5
diroffset = ndir*w*0.5

(You can easily remove one normalization and calculate one of the offsets by taking perpendicular from the other)

p0, p1, p2, p3 = polygon points:
p0 = start + perpoffset - diroffset
p1 = start - perpoffset - diroffset
p2 = end + perpoffset + diroffset
p3 = end - perpoffset + diroffset

P.S. You're the last person I ever going to explain this stuff to.
Things like these should be understood on intuitive level.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate this explanation, despite taking Alegebra 1 and 2 and Physics in high school I still have trouble with these things...

Answer (score 1):

The way to do with a straight line is to find the line perpendicular (N) to the original line, take a 5 pixels step in that direction and then find the perpendicular to the perpendicular in that point

```
  |     |
--+-----+---N
  |     |
  |     |
```

The way to do it with a non straight line is to approximate it with many straight lines or if you have the analytic representation of the line, to find some sort of analytic solution in a similar manner to the one of the straight line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this untested pseudo-code:

```
# Calculate the "Rise" and "run" (slope) of your input line, then 
# call this function, which returns offsets of x- and y-intercept
# for the parallel line.  Obviously the slope of the parallel line
# is already known: rise/run.

# returns (delta_x, delta_y) to be added to intercepts.  
adjacent_parallel(rise, run, distance, other_side):
    negate = other_side ? -1 : 1
    if rise == 0:
        # horizontal line; parallel is vertically away
        return (0, negate * distance)
    elif run == 0:
        # vertical line; parallel is horizontally away
        return (negate * distance, 0)
    else:
        # a perpendicular radius is - run / rise slope with length
        # run^2 + rize^2 = length  ^ 2
        nrml = sqrt(run*run + rise*rise)
        return (negate * -1 * run / nrml, negate * rise/nrml)
```

As SigTerm shows in his nice diagram, you will want to get the lines on either side of the intended line: so pass in `thickness/2` for distance and call twice, once with `other_side=true`, and draw a thickness centered on the 'abstract line'.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have some math background.

Start by understanding the [line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29) (linear equations and linear functions) what is a [parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_%28geometry%29) and benefit from looking up geometric [transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_%28geometry%29).

After that you will understand SigTerm's answer...